# flutter can't run debug on phone stucked on install android sdk toold

Tags: android, flutter, android-sdk-tools

```
    [+1576 ms] Welcome to Gradle 7.4!
[   +2 ms] Here are the highlights of this release:
[   +1 ms]  - Aggregated test and JaCoCo reports
[   +8 ms]  - Marking additional test source directories as tests in IntelliJ
[   +6 ms]  - Support for Adoptium JDKs in Java toolchains
[   +1 ms] For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/release-notes.html
[ +765 ms] Starting a Gradle Daemon, 6 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
[+30839 ms] Checking the license for package Android SDK Tools in C:\Users\barra\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\licenses
[  +98 ms] License for package Android SDK Tools accepted.
[   +3 ms] Preparing "Install Android SDK Tools (revision: 26.1.1)".
```

every time i try to compile and start debug flutter stuck on this point, this is a flutter run -v
On google chrome or edge it works

Comment: you need to install android sdk tools to run on android, if you are using android studio check on setting tabs, if fails run the ide on admin mode

Comment: are you using android studio

Comment: i'm using visual studio code with flutter plugin, i think is a bug of the project because on a new project it works fine